# Find the longest simple path in the graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Graph G is given by a list of edges (each element of the list is the number of an adjacent vertex): (1.4), (1.5), (1.6), (1.8), (2.3), (2.6 ), (3.8), (4.5), (4.7), (6.7), (7.8). I drew this graph[image], also wrote down its incidence matrix[image]. I need to find the longest simple path in the graph G. Please help to do that.

Comment: You can make a path to traverse all vertices (Hamiltonian), so that is clearly the longest possible path.

Comment: In this case, you can in fact exclude any chosen edge, or you could require any chosen edge, and still make a maximum-length path. The exclusion side follows directly because there is a Hamiltonian cycle, then the inclusion side is casework on edges not present in that cycle - including edge $(1,4)$ is marginally the trickiest (you must have $5$ as an endpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard call to standard software:

[image]

In *Mathematica*:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8},
  VertexLabels -> "Name"];

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g]]]
```